# Converter Timestamp to Date

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I am getting this timestamp (161128185939) from a legacy black box system. When trying to convert to date in java I'm getting 2/8/1975, but the correct one would be 2/8/2017. How to solve problem?

```
Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(161128185939L);
Date date = new Date(timeStamp.getTime());
```

Output: 1975-02-08

UPDATE:

It was sad to have discovered this, but due to the lack of documentation unfortunately happened. In fact this sequence is the date in the format yyMMddHHmmss which does not yet represent 2/8/2017 but instead 11/28/2016. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: If I test `161128185939` [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/), it also outputs 2/8/1975.

Comment: You first need to know what this number actually represents. Maybe it represents the umber of milliseconds since 2012-01-01, although that would be quite a strange choice.

Comment: Yes, you need to find out what starting point the timestamp uses, and which unit it is in (milliseconds, 8ths of seconds...).

Comment: Looks like some smarty tried to solve the [Y2K38 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) in that other system her own way... What is the exact difference to the correct timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

`161128185939L` is not the correct time of your date `2/8/2017` you can get the time using this :

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date = format.parse("2017/8/2");
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

This will show you `1501628400000`, so this is the correct time of your date, you can use this instead :

```
Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(1501628400000L);
Date date = new Date(timeStamp.getTime());
```